# Can't change datetime from time() to NOW ()

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I've got a line of code I'm trying to change... the original line was inserting Unix time, but I want CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or NOW. I've changed the field in the database to "datetime" type. However, when I change the code, I get the following error message: An error occurred while sending the message. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Here is the original code, followed by how I'm attempting to change it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Original code:

```
    //if(mysql_query('insert into pm (id, id2, title, user1, user2, message, date_time, user1read, user2read)values("'.$id.'", "'.(intval(mysql_num_rows($req2))+1).'", "", "'.$_SESSION['username'].'", "", "'.$message.'", "'.time().'", "", "")') and mysql_query('update pm set user'.$user_partic.'read="yes" where id="'.$id.'" and id2="1"'))
```

Modified Code:

```
    if(mysql_query('insert into pm (id, id2, title, user1, user2, message, date_time, user1read, user2read)values("'.$id.'", "'.(intval(mysql_num_rows($req2))+1).'", "", "'.$_SESSION['username'].'", "", "'.$message.'", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())') and mysql_query('update pm set user'.$user_partic.'read="yes" where id="'.$id.'" and id2="1"'))
```

Comment: You've removed the values for the last two fields in your INSERT query. You need to add `, "", ""` after `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: Oh GEEZ, that's embarrassing. *grin* For some reason, I was thinking those had something to do with formatting the time(). This is what happens when you've been working on a site since 4 a.m.!!! Thank you for your help!!!!!

Comment: No problem - sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes. Feel free to add it in as an answer and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

You have 9 items in your `INSERT` statement, but only 7 `VALUES`. The missing fields should be replaced with `""` as andrewsi suggested in the comments.

Formatting the query makes it more evident:

```
INSERT INTO pm (id, id2, title, user1, user2, message, date_time, user1read, user2read)
VALUES("'.$id.'",
       "'.(intval(mysql_num_rows($req2))+1).'",
       "",
       "'.$_SESSION['username'].'",
       "",
       "'.$message.'",
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

The correct query should be:

```
INSERT INTO pm (id, id2, title, user1, user2, message, date_time, user1read, user2read)
VALUES("'.$id.'",
       "'.(intval(mysql_num_rows($req2))+1).'",
       "",
       "'.$_SESSION['username'].'",
       "",
       "'.$message.'",
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
       "",
       "")
```

Hope this helps!